# How to connect jQuery autocomplete widget to a model?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, model, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery autocomplete widget (which I found here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple ) in my form for creating a new "Thing." Entering predetermined tags to choose from works beautifully, but I can't figure out how to make the widget choose from instances of my "Category" model. In other words, I want to associate each new thing with a few Categories. What should I change?

Things and Categories have_many of each other :through the intermediary model "CategoryThing". I'm using Rails 4.0.10.

Things/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Add Something!</h1>
<p>
  <%= form_for @thing, :url => things_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Name of the thing" %>
    <br>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
          <%= Category.pluck(:name).map { |name| "\"#{name}\"" }.join(",\n") %>
        ];
        function split( val ) {
          return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
          return split( term ).pop();
        }

        $( "#tags" )
          // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
          .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          })
          .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
              // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
              response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
              // prevent value inserted on focus
              return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
              var terms = split( this.value );
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push( ui.item.value );
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push( "" );
              this.value = terms.join( ", " );
              return false;
            }
          });
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Categories: </label>
      <input id="tags" size="50">
    </div>

    <%= f.label :related_things %>
    <%= f.collection_select :related_things, Thing.all, :id, :name %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :display_picture %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Things/controller:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    @category_things = CategoryThing.all
    @thing.categories.build
  end

  def new
    @thing = Thing.new
    @things = Thing.all
  end

  def create
    @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)
    if @thing.save
      redirect_to @thing
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def thing_params
      params.require(:thing).permit(:name, :image_path, :avatar, category_ids: [])
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the gem chosen-rails. Here is a tutorial for the gem https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails, but summarizing:

1) Add the gem to your gemfile

```
gem "chosen-rails"
```

2) Add the appropiate assets (js and css)
in *application.js*

```
//= require chosen-jquery
```

in *application.css.csss*

```
 *= require chosen
```

3) Add the class *chosen-select* to your field. e.g:

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_id , Product.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Seleccione un producto"}, {class: "chosen-select"} %>
```

4) Add to the coffescript code of your controller  this line, in my case *order_lines.js.coffee*

```
jQuery ->
```

$('.chosen-select').chosen()

Comment: Is multiselect available for that? I couldn't find anything in the Readme.